# Pip cannot install anything on ubuntu server

Tags: python, django, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I had deleted an existing virtual environment. I created a new one and activated it. Now I am trying to install site packages using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I keep getting the error

Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement BeautifulSoup==3.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

Now I know that the packages are really old but this is running on python  2.7.6. I am also not able to install anything through pip. I have tried

```
pip install numpy
```

But it shows the same errors. As per the similar questions answered before the suggestion is to use https://pypi.python.org which I have already done but still facing these errors.
Would love to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with having an old version of pip.

Try `pip install --upgrade pip` and then try installing the requirements again.

Answer (score 0):

pip tries to create lockfile in cache directory

Try running pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, you could improve your answer significantly, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer